# while refreshing the MKMapView, current location pin should move smoothly or animate to its current position

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkmapview

I have one problem: while refreshing the MKMapView the current location pin is not moving to its current position smoothly. How can I make it to move or animate smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom view for the pin and run a CABasicAnimation on the layer. This example does exactly that: https://github.com/100grams/Moving-MKAnnotationView